# How to allow only 1 number before and after the decimal point a texbox?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    CssClass="error"
    SetFocusOnError="true"   
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Error.."
    Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="txttextbox"    
    ValidationExpression="^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1}$"
    ValidationGroup="insert">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
    CssClass="error"
    SetFocusOnError="true"   
    runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Error.."
    Display="Dynamic"
    ControlToValidate="txttextbox"
    ValidationExpression="^\d{1}(\.\d{0,1})?$"    
    ValidationGroup="insert">
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/fIHC60BR0D)